# Django: Database caching to store web service result

Tags: python, django, database, caching

I have a method to load all ideas from `database`. There are few comments on each idea.

I have store `users id` who commented on ideas, in respective table.

I have a `web service` which contains all the data related to `user id`

When i load a page, it took time to fetch information for all users using web service.

I want to use `databse caching` to store that web service response and use that later on.

How to achieve this, to reduce page load timing?

when should i store that web service response in cache table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django documentation on the [cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/) is pretty easy to follow and will show you exactly how to set up a database cache for pages and other things in your views, including for how long you'd like the cache to exist, `TIMEOUT`, as well as other arguments a cache can take.

Another way to speed up accessing your DB information is to take advantage of `CONN_MAX_AGE` for your database in your `settings.py`, who's time can be dependent on how often the database needs to be accessed or how much traffic the site gets (as an example). This is basically letting your DB connection know how long to stay open, and can be found in the [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/) documentation.

You can store information in a cache when something on the site occurs (such as a new comment) or when that particular request is made for a particular page. It can be entirely up to the needs of your project.